# How to hide the main panel and show an image over the whole page?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a custom welcome page with an image on it but the main panel on the top remains to be displayed. For what I want to achieve see image below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  BitmapFileName: string;
  BitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  WelcomePage: TWizardPage;
begin
  WelcomePage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '', '');    

  BitmapFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DataNova_Logo.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile(ExtractFileName(BitmapFileName));

  BitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WelcomePage);
  BitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
  BitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(BitmapFileName);
  BitmapImage.Cursor := crHand;
  BitmapImage.Left := 10;
  BitmapImage.Top := 10;
  BitmapImage.Parent := WelcomePage.Surface;
end;
```

How to show the image over the whole page with the main panel hidden ?

Comment: If you do not want to use your own solution I can recommend you this project for creating cool skinned Inno installers:http://graphical-installer.com. Picture: http://graphical-installer.com/joomla/images/stories/gallery/projects/gallery-18.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to hide the `Bevel1`, `MainPanel` and the `InnerNotebook` components when you switch to your welcome page and show them again when you leave it. As the opposite, the image you need to show only when you're showing your welcome page since it covers the whole page area. So the following code will do the trick:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  WelcomePageID: Integer;
  BitmapImage: TBitmapImage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  WelcomePage: TWizardPage;  
begin
  WelcomePage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '', '');
  WelcomePageID := WelcomePage.ID;
  BitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\Image.bmp');
  BitmapImage.Top := 0;
  BitmapImage.Left := 0;
  BitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
  BitmapImage.Cursor := crHand;
  BitmapImage.Visible := False;
  BitmapImage.Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  BitmapImage.Visible := CurPageID = WelcomePageID;
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := CurPageID <> WelcomePageID;
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := CurPageID <> WelcomePageID;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := CurPageID <> WelcomePageID;
end;
```

Comment: For a similar questions, see [Inno Setup - Image as installer background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41049054/850848) (background image over whole window) or [Image covering whole page in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44471989/850848) (background image over whole page, between "header" and "footer").