# Display image in top panel of Inno Setup wizard instead of page title and description

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to put an image in the space on the top of the wizard, as shown in the picture. And hide the page title and description.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Cover the `MainPanel` with an image and hide all its other components (`WizardSmallBitmapImage`, `PageDescriptionLabel` and `PageNameLabel`):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "rainbow.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  BitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('rainbow.bmp');
  BitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BitmapImage.Parent := WizardForm.MainPanel;
  BitmapImage.Width := WizardForm.MainPanel.Width;
  BitmapImage.Height := WizardForm.MainPanel.Height;
  { Needed for WizardStyle=modern in Inno Setup 6. Must be removed in Inno Setup 5. }
  BitmapImage.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  BitmapImage.Stretch := True;
  BitmapImage.AutoSize := False;
  BitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\rainbow.bmp'));
  
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

---

[image: Rainbow Wizard]

---

See also:

- [How to hide the main panel and show an image over the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142870/850848)
- [Inno Setup - Transparency under text in page name and description labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46178215/850848)
- [Adjust Inno Setup MainPanel to banner image size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62907577/850848)