# Change size of Inno Setup page name and description labels

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using this solution:
[Display image in top panel of Inno Setup wizard instead of page title and description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684039/display-image-in-top-panel-of-inno-setup-wizard-instead-of-page-title-and-descri)

And I want set parameters like this:

```pascal
WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Visible := False;
WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Color := clBlack;
WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Color := clBlack;
WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Font.Color := clWhite;
WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Font.Color := clWhite;
```

but... i don't know how to make black backgrounds shorter under title and description. As you can see black strips going on to the face. It is possible at all?

I want something like this:

[image: look]

Already i have this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change labels width use theirs `.Width` property.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // ...

  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width :=
    WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Width - ScaleX(120);

  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width :=
    WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Width - ScaleX(120);
end;
```

[image]

---

Or you can make the labels transparent:
[Inno Setup - Transparency under text in page name and description labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46178215/850848)