# Inno Setup - Transparency under text in page name and description labels

Tags: inno-setup

I want make transparency under text here:

[image]

As you can see, I have black background what i don't want to have.

Greetings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PageNameLabel` and `PageDescriptionLabel` are `TNewStaticText` components. This component does not support transparency. Though `TLabel` component, which has similar functionality otherwise, does support transparency ([in Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) and with themed Windows only).

So, you can replace those two components with `TLabel` equivalent. And then you need to make sure, that captions of your new custom components get updated, whenever Inno Setup does update the original components. For these two components, this is quite easy, as they get updated only, when a page changes. So you can update your custom components from [`CurPageChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged).

```pascal
function CloneStaticTextToLabel(StaticText: TNewStaticText): TLabel;
begin
  Result := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Result.Parent := StaticText.Parent;
  Result.Left := StaticText.Left;
  Result.Top := StaticText.Top;
  Result.Width := StaticText.Width;
  Result.Height := StaticText.Height;
  Result.AutoSize := StaticText.AutoSize;
  Result.ShowAccelChar := StaticText.ShowAccelChar;
  Result.WordWrap := StaticText.WordWrap;
  Result.Font := StaticText.Font;
  StaticText.Visible := False;
end;

var
  PageDescriptionLabel: TLabel;
  PageNameLabel: TLabel;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { ... }

  { Create TLabel equivalent of standard TNewStaticText components }
  PageNameLabel := CloneStaticTextToLabel(WizardForm.PageNameLabel);
  PageDescriptionLabel := CloneStaticTextToLabel(WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  { Update the custom TLabel components from the standard hidden components }
  PageDescriptionLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption;
  PageNameLabel.Caption := WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Caption;
end;
```

[image]

---

Way easier is to change original labels background color:
[Inno Setup - Change size of page name and description labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46172021/850848)

Comment: Yeah. I installed the Unicode version of Inno Setup and everything works fine. Thanks for everything.