# Inno Setup - Image as installer background

Tags: inno-setup

Image as installer background. How to do that with inno 5.5.9?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible in Inno Setup proper. Maybe is some Inno Setup clone.

The problem is that all labels in Inno Setup are `TStaticText`, which is not transparent. So you would have to replace all with `TLabel`. And there's a lot of them. And they are managed by Inno Setup. So you would somehow have to continuously update the new `TStaticText`'s to the values set to original `TLabel`'s by the Inno Setup. It may not even be possible.

---

So actually, it's possible to create a page like in your question. But only because there are no standard Inno Setup labels. But you cannot hide all of them.

[image: Installer with background image]

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  BackImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  { Hide top panel }
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := False;

  { Adjust "select dir" page controls for a stretched inner page size }
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Left :=
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Left + WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Left;
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Top := WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Top;
  WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Left :=
    WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Left + WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Left;
  WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Top :=
    WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Top + WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Top;

  { Hide non-transparent labels }    
  WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.SelectDirBrowseLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.SelectDirLabel.Visible := False;

  { Stretch the outer page across whole form }
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Width := WizardForm.ClientWidth;
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height := WizardForm.ClientHeight;

  { Stretch the inner page across whole outer page }
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Left := 0;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Top := 0;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Width := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.ClientWidth;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.ClientHeight;
 
  { Put buttons on top of the page (image) }
  WizardForm.BackButton.BringToFront()
  WizardForm.NextButton.BringToFront();
  WizardForm.CancelButton.BringToFront();

  { Add a background image }    
  BackImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BackImage.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  BackImage.Top := 0;
  BackImage.Left := 0;  
  { ... }
  BackImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(...);
end;
```

---

Similar questions:

- Displaying a background image above "footer" only:
  [How to hide the main panel and show an image over the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142870/850848)
- Displaying a background image between "header" and "footer" only:
  [Image covering whole page in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44471989/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try **[Graphical Installer](http://graphical-installer.com/joomla/%20Graphical%20Installer) for Inno Setup** which is specially designed for this purpose.

With it you can create cool looking installers and they support changing background (this picture is from last project for Shadow Tactics game) mod:

[image: Graphical Installer example]

I am developer of this project (commercial) so if you need more info feel free to ask.