# Wizard Video in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I trying to know whether an video can be put in background of an setup. I am not talking about video as background we do with media player.dll and bass.dll 
I am Talking about video in the setup but as background like we put an image in setup for example
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRpiH.png)
Like this installer we had an image of a soldier can we replace the image by an video playing in background 
So that will more cool 
Hope u got my question.

Comment: It's hardly possible with static image, let only with video. See [Inno Setup - Image as installer background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41049054/850848) - You would have to use some Inno Setup clone for sure.

Comment: Video can only settled in whole background or fixed size but not in background right ??ettled Can any external dll we can use to do that or like vcl style we need software???

Comment: I cannot answer that. I'm not a fan of styled installers.

Comment: And what about animated gifs ?? Can they can be put in the background like in replace of that image soldier?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: Means have to use delphi.