# Image covering whole page in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Following on from this: [Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696537/inno-setup-placing-image-control-on-custom-page).

This is doing what I need:

```pascal
CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpLicense, 'Heading', 'Sub heading.');

ExtractTemporaryFile('image.bmp');

BtnImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
with BtnImage do
begin
  Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\image.bmp');
  AutoSize := True;
  AutoSize := False;
  Height := ScaleX(Height);
  Width := ScaleY(Width);
  Stretch := True;
  Left := ScaleX(90);
  Top := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Top + WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Height -
         Height - ScaleY(8);
  Cursor := crHand;
  OnClick := @ImageOnClick;
end;
```

However I would like the background image to be the full size of the space bellow the heading and above the footer with no side margins. I was trying various stretch/margin/height/width, but the results are messy. What's the best way to achieve this that looks good no matter the DPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve a size of the (custom) page surface using [`TWizardPage.SurfaceHeight` and `TWizardPage.SurfaceWidth`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage).

```pascal
BtnImage.Height := CustomPage.SurfaceHeight;
BtnImage.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
// Needed for WizardStyle=modern
BtnImage.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
```

Though you will see that the (custom) page does not cover whole area between "header" (`MainPanel`) and "footer" (bottom part with buttons).

[image]

---

If you want to display image across the whole area between "header" and "footer", you cannot place it on the (custom) page. You have to place it on the `InnerPage` (what is a parent control of all pages with the "header").

```pascal
BtnImage.Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;

BtnImage.Left := 0;
BtnImage.Top := WizardForm.Bevel1.Top + 1;
BtnImage.Width := WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientWidth;
BtnImage.Height := WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientHeight - BtnImage.Top;
// Needed for WizardStyle=modern
BtnImage.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
```

But that way the image won't get automatically shown/hidden as the custom page shows/hides. You have to code it. Use [`CurPageChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged).

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.InnerNoteBook.Visible := (CurPageID <> CustomPage.ID);
  BtnImage.Visible := (CurPageID = CustomPage.ID);
end;
```

[image]

---

Similar questions:

- An alternative implementation that resizes the "pages" to cover whole upper parts of the wizard window:
  [Can you create a custom page that looks like the Finish page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65619515/850848)
- Displaying an image even over the "header":
  [How to hide the main panel and show an image over the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142870/850848)
- Displaying an image as a background of whole window: [Inno Setup - Image as installer background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41049054/850848).