# How can I place the image on the very left on the custom page as well as it's placed on Welcome and Finished pages? (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

I've created a custom page and I need to place the image on it as well as it's done for the Welcome and Finished pages. So I need it to look like this:

[image]

But I have this instead:

[image]

Here's some code:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  bmpiWizardLeftSideImage: TBitmapImage; 
begin
  wpSelectInstallTypePage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallTypePageCaption}'), ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallTypePageDescription}'));
  bmpiWizardLeftSideImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with bmpiWizardLeftSideImage do
  begin
    Parent := wpSelectInstallTypePage.Surface;
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Images\InstallImage.bmp');
    AutoSize := True;
    Left := 0;
    Height := ScaleX(Height);
    Width := ScaleY(Width); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Start here: [Image covering whole page in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44471989/850848).