# How to add a new page to Inno Setup OuterNotebook?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

As part of an installer I'm working on using Inno Setup, I need to replicate the `wpWelcome`, page but with a different content. I've created a `TNotebookPage`, added the image, panel and content I want and it displays as expected. However I'm not sure how to add it to the `WizardForm` at the location I want. I can force it to appear as the first page, but clicking next/back shifts make the page disappear.

How do I insert the notebook page into the `OuterNotebook` at the relevant position?

```pascal
function CreatePage: TNewNoteBookPage;
var
  page: TNewNoteBookPage;
begin 
  page := TNewNoteBookPage.Create( WizardForm );
  page.Notebook := WizardForm.OuterNotebook;
  page.Align := alClient;
  page.Color := clWindow;
  page.Visible:= True;

  Result := page;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  myPage: TNewNoteBookPage;
begin
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
  myPage := CreatePage();

  { how do I specify where I want the page in the OuterNotebook? }
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's suggestions were very helpful, whilst not solving the problem directly they gave me an idea. I needed more than just a image covering the window. Hence my solution was to create a `TNoteBookPage` which I could format as needed and also a `TWizardPage`. Since the notebookpage couldn't be added to the installer without breaking inno-setup's ordering, I used the custom page to maintain ordering and when the CustomPage was set active, I switch the active page to be the notebook page hence showing what I needed.

```pascal
[Code]
Apage, TWizardPage;
ANotebookPage: TNewNoteBookPage;

function CreatePage: TNewNoteBookPage;
var
  page: TNewNoteBookPage;
  sideBarImage: TBitmapImage;
  panel: TPanel;
begin 

  {create page, sidebar and panel for our main content}
  page := TNewNoteBookPage.Create( WizardForm );
  page.Notebook := WizardForm.OuterNotebook;
  page.Align := alClient;
  page.Color := clWindow;
  page.Visible:= True;

  { copies the already loaded sidebar image on the welcome page to this notebook page}
  sideBarImage := TBitmapImage.Create( WizardForm );
  sideBarImage.Bitmap := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap;       
  sideBarImage.Top := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Top;
  sideBarImage.Left := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Left;
  sideBarImage.Width := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width;
  sideBarImage.Height := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Height;
  sideBarImage.BackColor := WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.BackColor;
  sideBarImage.Parent := page;

  panel := TPanel.Create( WizardForm );
  panel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  panel.Color  := clWindow;
  panel.Parent := page;
  panel.Left   := sideBarImage.Width + ScaleX(10);
  panel.Height := page.Height;
  panel.Width  := page.Width - sideBarImage.Width;

  { at this point we have a panel we can populate with content }

  Result := page
end

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ANotebookPage := CreateOneClickInstallPage();
  APage := CreateCustomPage( wpLicense, 'Install', '');
end

procedure CurPageChanged( CurPageID: Integer );
begin
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := true;
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := true;
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := true;

  if CurPageID = APage.ID then begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall)  
    WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := false;
    WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := false;
    WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := false;
    WizardForm.OuterNotebook.ActivePage := ANoteBookPage;
  end;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you specify a page position using `TNewNotebookPage.PageIndex`. But I'm afraid that by "manually" modifying the `OuterNotebook` you break an inner Inno Setup logic.

---

Why don't you just modify the existing Welcome page, instead of creating a new one?

See, for example, [Custom Welcome and Finished page with stretched image in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34705492/850848).

---

Alternatively, create a custom page on the `InnerNotebook`, but expand it to cover a whole window.

See [How to hide the main panel and show an image over the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142870/850848)